# How do I set Data on a Javascript Clipboard?

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIClipboard

When I listen to a paste event in javascript, I am able to get paste data out of the clipboards as a string like so:

```
let pastedText: string = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

or like so for those not using typescript:

```
var pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

I am trying to re-send this event with edited clipboard data. I can re-issue the event, but I am having trouble using clipboard's `setData` method. I am trying this ([documentation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctuhrg.php)):

```
 e.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'lolData');
```

but when I run:

```
  console.log('NEW CLIPBOARD DATA: ');
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
```

Nothing is printed. I don't really understand what I am doing with trying to set on the event, but it seems to make sense, since I am getting it from the event object.

Comment: Browser? did u read the restrictions?

Comment: Latest Chrome. I did not read the restrictions.

Comment: This is what they say (dont know if this is up to date)In Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, use the execCommand method with the 'Paste' command to retrieve and with the 'Copy' command to set the text content of the clipboard. Because of security restrictions, this method may not always work, see Example 2 for details.

Comment: I see it now, thanks. Fun.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36380702/2581562)

Comment: or if u need to use it all over ur site
https://clipboardjs.com/
It's cross-browser...

Comment: That helps. thanks.