# How to set Image to clipboardData in oncopy event

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

I want to implement **ctrl+c** event in canvas (like in painters) from selected region to OS buffer. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380702/3872976) answer I can add `copy` listener and change clipboard data there - which works perfectly with text. But I can't find how to put `Image`/`ImageData` object there there. Here's MDN [copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy) documentation and [setData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData). Seems like there is nothing about `image/*` format. Well [Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-setdata) doesn't say anything as well. But I smell if first param named as `format` in `setData` there should be a way to put file there.

Here's where I come so far:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
   var data = ctx.getImageData(params.left, params.top, params.width, params.height);
   var file = new File(data.data, "file.png", {type: "image/png"});
   e.clipboardData.items.add(file, 'image/png'); // This doesn't work, But it create the structure like on the image below(with items and types, but without FileList) 
   e.clipboardData.setDragImage(tool.img, 10, 10); // doesn't work 
   e.clipboardData.setData("image/png", tool.file); // doesn't work
   e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

I also found [setDragImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage) method, I implemented it but after putting `Image` it doesn't appear in buffer.

**NOTE:**

When I paste image **FROM** clipboard my 'paste' event shows event structure like on the image bellow, so I guess I need create something similar.[image]

Any Ideas?

p.s. I also know about [document.execCommand('copy');](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547470/3872976), but it doesn't work in chrome (at least in my case) so I don't wanna use it.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking only from my observations and investigation:

- Chrome does not support the `"image/png"` type, and this is not a format that is required by the Clipboard API spec. ([Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150835).)
- Firefox will at least attempt to put a DataTransferItem with the `"image/png"` type on the clipboard, but I haven't yet figured out what data format to use. (A base64 PNG, with or without the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix, does not work to paste into PowerPoint, nor does `atob(<the base64 PNG without prefix>)`, as far as I've experimented.)
- `"text/html"` is required however. When a `copy` event is triggered in Google Docs, it appears to upload an image, then puts an HTML fragment on the clipboard that looks like this:

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-abcdefg-abcd-abcd">
    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/a-very-long-identifier" width="659px;" height="312px;" />
  </b>
  ```

  using `evt.clipboardData.setData("text/html", fragment)`. Then, e.g. Microsoft Office apps will download that image and embed it in the document. I don't know if it does the same thing on MacOS or Linux. Data URIs do not work as the `img` `src`, by the way.